# Using Regex to Erase After Second Colon in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Hello!**

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I spent some time searching previous posts, but I was unable to find the answer to this simple issue I cannot seem to figure out.

Using Notepad++ and Regex with the replace function, I am trying to turn a sample string like this:

**Original Text**

State:Minnesota:Data

**Desired Output**

State:Minnesota

I thought I had found the answer with simply using **:.*** in the Find and leaving the Replace blank, but regex for whatever reason has always been a struggle for me.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is `State:Minnesota:Data` the entirety of the string? Or are there some other characters surrounding it? Will the string have 4 or more colons? Do you still want to remove the characters after the second colon if there are 4 colons?

Comment: `:.*` removes all from the first colon including the colon itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
^(.*?:.*?):.*
```

Or,

```
^([^:\r\n]*:[^:\r\n]*):.*
```

And replace with `$1`.

**Details**

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `(.*?:.*?)` - captures into Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible, then a colon, and then again any 0 or more chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible (`[^:\r\n]` matches any char but a colon, an LF and CR chars)
- `:` - a colon
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Screenshot:
[image]